# What is HeapSizePerGCThread in Java heap memory size

Tags: java, linux, memory, heap-memory

I want to compare the configuration of two servers and 
I have supposed to check the java heap memory size in my servers, in one of the  servers the value HeapSizePerGCThread has been set to 8 Mb and it has java version of 1.7 and in the another one it hasn't been set and it has java version 1.6.

Both the servers has the same configuration (RAM,ROM,CPUs).

My question is that OK to set the value HeapSizePerGCThread in the server which has java version 1.6.

Comment: See this Stackoverflow question:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26631784/57217