# JVM MaxHeapSize := 0 - what does this mean?

Tags: java, jvm

I have seen other questions on here like: [How is the default max Java heap size determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667483/how-is-the-default-max-java-heap-size-determined) and [Understanding java heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631498/understanding-java-heap)

I run the command to see my heap size `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version` and I get the output for MaxHeapSize:

`uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 0                                   {product}`

What does this mean?

Comment: This means, you run 64-bit JDK 8 (or earlier) on Windows, and the maximum heap size (-Xmx) is the exact multiple of 4 GiB.

Comment: I just verified this by running `java -Xmx4g -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version` and could reproduce `MaxHeapSize := 0`. Can you elaborate on why this is the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in JDK 8.

`MaxHeapSize` is [defined](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/741cd0f77fac/src/share/vm/runtime/globals.hpp#l3191) in HotSpot sources as `uintx`, which stands for 64-bit unsigned integer.

In JDK 8, the [format](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/741cd0f77fac/src/share/vm/runtime/globals.cpp#l308) for printing `uintx` flag values is `"%-16lu"`, which treats input as `unsigned long`.

However, the size of C++ `unsigned long` [differs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) on Windows and Unix:

- Most Unix-like systems are LP64, where the size of `unsigned long` is 64 bit.
- Visual C++ on Windows is LLP64, where the size of `unsigned long` is 32 bit.

So, JDK 8 on Windows prints only low 32 bits of `uintx` flags. That's why if `MaxHeapSize` is an exact multiple of 4 GiB, you'll see `uintx MaxHeapSize := 0`. This is just the printing error; the actual max heap size is correct.

The bug was fixed in JDK 9 as a part of [JDK-8042893](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8042893) change:

```
     } else if (is_uintx()) {
-      st->print("%-16lu", get_uintx());
+      st->print(UINTX_FORMAT_W(-16), get_uintx());
```

Comment: And if your JVM is hit by the bug, the only practical solution is to **upgrade** to Java 11.